# Displaying multiple items in Excel graph and few calculation issues

Tags: excel, graph, vba

I've done some Googling for each of my issues but haven't found exactly the results as I wanted. Things I need to be done doesn’t probably include any macros/VBA skills, just basic knowledge of Excel.

Now to my spreadsheet. I'm a Dota 2 player and I like statistics. I like it that much that I'd like to keep track of my achievements and results. Only problem is that the game tracker sucks and to get great information in web you have to pay for it, so I decided it's time for me to create my own spreadsheet to track my skills.

I don't know which place is the best to share my spreadsheet but I uploaded it to Estonian uploading host, link is [here](http://www.upload.ee/files/4804247/coolerMMR.xlsx.html). I will also provide with pictures so you don't have to download anything.

This is what it looks like in general:

[image]

Problem number 1: The left table, or column has 1000 rows. In web design it's possible to make elements fixed depending on the scroll, I'd like to use similar feature here. If the table gets scrolled down, the right table (area with games, bonus and graph) will get scrolled down with it.

Problem number 2: Average MMR. I'd like to show average MMR after each entry depending on the first entries. Right now there's avg MMR for J4:J8. The calculation for J8 looks like this: `=AVERAGE(C4:C8)`. For J7 it looks like this: `=AVERAGE(C4:C7)`. I'd like to do this for all my 1000 rows, but I don't want to type it out. If I try to drag down from the corner, it will continue with C5:C8, C6:C9 etc (so it changes the starting point)

Problem number 3: Under longestGame there's currently Date and Hero. This should show the Date and Hero of which the longest game occurred. I tried to do this with LOOKUP function but it required table to be in ascending order, which I don't want. For current, 44,22, there should be Storm Spirit and 14.06.2015.

Problem number 4: Graph. I'd like to display three series on graph - MMR, average MMR and game length (time). The problem is, that MMR and average MMR will be in the numbers on 3000-7000 but the game length will only be probably in timeframe 20:00-120:00. Maybe it's possible to add two sets of values to the Y axis or maybe set Time series maximum 200:00 and minimum 0:00 and create graph according to this. I'm really stupid making graphs and I haven't figured out a clever way yet.

Problem number 5: Graph again. Right now I have to set the series for the graph. I've currently set it to C4:C54 (so 50 rows). I'd like it to move around a bit and by that I mean that if there happens to be C55-th game then the graph would start from C5:C55 and move along (so it'll count 50 last games).

Comment: I expect this would be better on _Super User_, since it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in a benevolent mood so rather than downvoting your question, because it is not really suitable for this forum I'm going to give you some hints and guidance. The numbers below correspond to the problems in your question.

1. Excel permits more than one window to be used on the same workbook -
   so one window can show the data and one the summary.
2. Find out about absolute and relative cell addressing - its a valuable bit of knowledge for anyone serious about Excel and it will be of use in solving your problem.
3. Find out about the MATCH function. You can use this to find out which row of your table contains the longest game, shortest game, max MMR, min MMR by matching an element from the summary on the right (cols M onward) against the appropriate column table on the left. The find out about the INDEX function - this can be used to pull the values in the columns for Hero and Date which correspond to a specific row (such as the row containing the longest game, shortest game, etc). Search INDEX MATCH and find out why using these two functions in combination is often preferred to using the VLOOKUP function
4. Persevere - there are graph options available to do what you want and the only way to really learn is to go through the pain of trying them out, failing and working at it until you succeed.
5. Set up an area of worksheet to hold the 50*3 table of data for your graphs. Find out about the COUNT function and think how it might be of use in determining which rows of the data table map to the 50 rows of graph data. Then think about how to populate the graph data table using one of the functions mentioned above. Incidentally, C4:C54 is actually 51 rows, not 50.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i'll try them out!